# ORACLE: Sorting a String field containing numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to display page number in ascending order. But, since the field PAGE is of String datatype, normal 'ORDER BY' considers 10 < 2. I have to make the field PAGE as String because there can be inputs like '3-4'. Can anyone please suggest a way out. I've attached screenshot for reference.

Kindly help.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg2JA.jpg)

```
select id
    ,F_NL
    ,page
    ,title
from newsletter_content
where F_NL = '29'
order by page asc;
```

Comment: Could you give us what did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm actually out of ideas. I thought of changing the Java code but it will be better if I can display it in the correct way using queries.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: So how do you expect to sort a "page number" of `3-4`???

Comment: Are there any other special page numbers (e.g. 'A', 'page 12', '1+2', '3f', '4ff', '1.5', '1,2,3')? Or only numbers ('1', '2', ...) and number ranges ('1-2', '3-5', ...)?

Comment: In case there can only be single pages and page ranges, I'd suggest you change your table design and switch to two numeric columns `from_page` and `till_page`. That would make such tasks much easier and prevent from invalid data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, Thorsten for your valuable inputs. There are 2 possible inputs, either, 1, 2, 3, etc. OR 1-2, 3-4, and so on..
However, the answers given by Ponder and MT0 works well. This is what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select page from p 
  order by to_number(nvl(substr(page, 1, instr(page, '-')-1), page))
```

**<sup>[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/BXOY90540)</sup>**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the presence of a `-` character and extract the preceding number:

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN INSTR( page, '-' ) > 0
           THEN TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( page, 1, INSTR( page, '-' ) - 1 ) )
           ELSE TO_NUMBER( page )
         END;
```